# How get arrays of strings properties from list of objects

Tags: java, arrays, list

How I can get an array of category `String`s from a `List<Book>` with only unique values?

I tried with stream but I miss something.

```
class Book {
    int id;
    String[] categories;

//    getters and setters 

}

List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
    new Book(1,{"Java" , "Computers"}),
    new Book(1,{"Python" , "C++" }),
    new Book(1,{"Java" , "IT"})
);

books.stream().map(VolumeInfo::getCategories).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Another variant could be : `String[] arr = books.stream().map(Book::getCategories).flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet()).stream().toArray(String[]::new);` No need of distinct because a *Set* can't have duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw in a call to [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) to only get unique values. However, since `getCategories` returns a `String[]` you'll need to `flatMap` to get a single `String[]` as a result:

```
String[] arr = books.stream()
                    .map(Book::getCategories)
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .distinct()
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Which will produce the `Array`:

```
[Java, Computers, Python, C++, IT]
```

Comment: Ok but then I get a List of arrays but I want to get all values in one array

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Thats what I needed.